# Preventing OnChange Dropdown jump effect or avoid scrolling to the top of the page

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, scrollbar

I have 2 dropdowns that loads some divs in 3 * 3 matrix., changing one or the other shows dynamic content, (non ajax, just simple show and hide other div's)

Since the page is long , browser produces the scroll bar.

the problem that i am facing is that once you scroll down to the bottom of the page , and change the dropdown ,the page scrolls to top, or has a jump effect . I want to retain the focus on the dropdowns once they are change so that i can avoid the jump effect.

I tried event.preventDefault and event.stopPropagation() , but i still see the issue.

Was wondering if anyone has any insight on how can i solve this.

This is happening in all the  browsers.

```
<script language="javascript">
                                var jQ132 = $.noConflict(true);
                                jQ132(document).ready(function () {

                                jQ132("#TechnologyDiv").hide();
                                jQ132("#MarketSelect").appendTo("#MarketDiv");
                                jQ132("#TechnologyDiv").show();


                                    var divsinsidecontainer = jQ132("#storiescontainer > div");

                                       jQ132("#TechnologySelect").change(function (e) {                                            
                                        var techSel = jQ132(this).val();

                                        if (techSel == "all") {                                                
                                            divsinsidecontainer.show();
                                        }
                                        else {

                                            divsinsidecontainer.hide();
                                            divsinsidecontainer.each(function () {
                                                if (jQ132(this).attr('data-class').indexOf(techSel) > -1)
                                                    jQ132(this).show();
                                            });                                               
                                        }

                                        jQ132("#MarketSelect").val(0);


                                    });

                                    jQ132("#MarketSelect").change(function (e) {                                            
                                        var marketSel = jQ132(this).val();

                                        if (marketSel == "all") {
                                            divsinsidecontainer.show();
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            divsinsidecontainer.hide();
                                            divsinsidecontainer.each(function () {
                                                if (jQ132(this).attr('data-class').indexOf(marketSel) > -1)
                                                    jQ132(this).show();

                                            });                                                
                                        }
                                        jQ132("#TechnologySelect").val(0);


                                    });

                                });

                                   </script>
```

Comment: Hi Rahul. I currently have the same problem, could you solve the issue?